# Can't access MySQL DB after failed import

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

Set off a mysql import which ultimately failed due to HD space being maxed out.

Since then, I'm not able to drop either the table it was being loaded to or the DB the table belongs to (only one table in the DB), and am otherwise unable to access it via a simple `USE` command.

The other DBs work as expected and I'm able to log in/out without issue.

Would simply like to 'start from scratch', remove the impacted DB and table, and recreate the DB to try the import again having made space accommodations.  Best way to debug this?

Comment: Show the exact error message. Also, you'll find better answers on https://dba.stackexchange.com/